# Dynamic pull down menu in Eclipse not working

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to create an eclipse plugin implemented in the form of a dynamic dropdown menu. The contents of the dropdown menu must be filled dynamically. I am able to add contents statically however the dynamic implementation is what i really what.

I see [Static and dynamic pulldown menus](http://codeandme.blogspot.sg/2013/01/static-and-dynamic-pulldown-menus.html) article and followed the steps to create dynamic pull down menu .

However as I try to implement the dynamic part the plugin doesn't load in Eclipse. I don't see any errors in the console either.

I did the following:

1. Right click on my `org.eclipse.ui.menus` and added a menu contribution
2. I right clicked on the added contribution and added dynamic node to it.
3. I implemented the dynamic class.

Resulting XML:

```
 <menuContribution
       allPopups="false"
       locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">
    <dynamic
          class="org.eclipse.ui.articles.action.contribution.DynamicContributionItem"
          id="org.eclipse.ui.articles.action.contribution.dynamic3">
    </dynamic>
 </menuContribution>
```

My implemented class named `DynamicContributionItem` is never called. I can't figure out what could be wrong?

Is there a better way to create a dynamic dropdown than what is mentioned here?

Comment: Is your plug-in loaded ? (please check that `Activator.start()` is called)

Comment: @scawf i think it is because besides the dynamic dropdown menu my plug-in also contributes other UI components which get rendered properly . Only the dynamic dropdown menu doesnt.

Comment: It depends. Statics menu does NOT need the plug-in to be loaded to be "kind-of" working. But yes, if you have a custom view opened, your plug-in is loaded.